# Storing temporary variables for use in Loopback 4 application

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

I have an authentication token I'd like to use in multiple Loopback 4 controllers. This token expires. Once expired I run some login logic to fetch a new token.

My issue is I'm not sure how or where to store this token.

So I can use this throughout my application I'm thinking to either save the token as a environment variable eg.

```
process.env.AUTH_TOKEN = 'TEST';
```

or use Loopback 4's Application-level context
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Context.html

**Are these suitable solutions for storing this token? If not what would be an alternative solution?**

**In the case of using Context, how would I go about doing this using best practices?**

Comment: What kind of token is it? Is it a single token per application or per user of that application or probably something else?

Comment: How do detect that a token is expired and which part of your app calls the the action to fetch a new token?

Comment: @PeterLiapin The token is used to interact with a REST API I have set up using the loopback/service-proxy module. My use case is single token per application.

Comment: @MiroslavBajtoš If I try to interact with the REST API and I receive an auth error, I intend on running the login logic to fetch and save a new token. The REST API also provides a “Keep alive” endpoint I could use.

Comment: @MiroslavBajtoš To answer the second part of your question. I have a controller which periodically requests and saves data from a REST API using the service-proxy module. If the request receives an auth error, this controller accesses a “login” controller which fetches (using the same service) and saves a new token. Then the original request is attempted again.

Comment: @pessato have you thought about the multi-nodes scenario, will it be ok if each node will have to request a separate token or do you want them all to share the same token?

Comment: @PeterLiapin this application was only going to run on a single node as it has a small lightweight use case. However I see where you're going, for the majority of applications best practice would be saving the token to a datasource?

Comment: Yes, but even in a single node you usually have multiple node instances running with pm2 or something similar. Otherwise a single node process can easily fail. Is or not a problem in your case?

Comment: @PeterLiapin My use case specifically is this application will run like a bot. Requesting data from a REST API periodically using a scheduled task. Even if the process fails it can just reboot, login again and request a new token. On reflection however I might be trying to be a bit too "cute" here. Saving the token to the datasource is probably a better way to handle the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking all the comments above into account I would recommend you to crate a separate module which will encapsulate the logic related to your authentication token and how you use it. I.e. a new module will be responsible for:

- Fetching a new token when it is empty
- Storing of the token
- Refreshing the token when it has expired
- Execution of the API calls (or whatever you do with that token, sorry it was not clear from your description) - can be moved to a separate module, but it is a different story

I imagine your module in JavaScript may look something like:

```js
let AUTH_TOKEN = "";

function makeAPICall(some, params) {
    if (! AUTH_TOKEN) {
        acquireNewToken();
    }

    if (expired()) {
        refreshToken();
    }

    return "some_data"; // TODO: here you do you what you want with your auth token and return some data
}

function acquireNewToken() {
    authToken = "new_token"; // TODO: put the logic to acquire a new token here
}

function refreshToken() {
    authToken = "new_token"; // TODO: put the logic to refresh a token here
}

function expired() {
    return false; // TODO: put the logic to check if token expired here
}

module.exports = {
    makeAPICall: makeAPICall
};
```

Then you can `require` the `authModule` in all your controllers and use it like below:

```js
let authModule = require('./modules/authModule');

authModule.makeAPICall("some", "params");
```

I believe you will never need to expose the auth token to your controllers as you can implement all the logic related to auth token usage within the `authModule` and only pass some parameters to `makeAPICall` function to tell it what to do and which data to get. But in case if you really need to expose it you can change the `authModule` a bit (add `getToken` function and add it to `module.exports`):

```
function getToken() {
    return authToken;
}

module.exports = {
    makeAPICall: makeAPICall,
    getToken: getToken
};
```

Now, let's get back to your questions:

> Are these suitable solutions for storing this token? If not what would be an alternative solution?

As proposed above the solution is to store the token as a local variable in scope of custom module. Note, as [Node.js uses caching for modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) your `AUTH_TOKEN` variable will be the same across all the controllers (every new `require` will return you  exactly the same object with the same token).

If you do not want to `require` the `authModule` every time you need to access your `AUTH_TOKEN` you can also simply declare it as a global variable: `global.AUTH_TOKEN = "";`. Note, that global variables have it's drawback like it may cause implicit coupling between files, etc. Here is a good article about when you should and when you should not use global variables: https://stackabuse.com/using-global-variables-in-node-js/

> In the case of using Context, how would I go about doing this using
>   best practices?

You can use Loopback 4 Context as well and it will be almost an equivalent of the solution with the custom `authModule` I proposed above. The only difference with the customer module - you can put a bit more custom logic there and avoid copy-pasting some of your code in the controllers. With Loopback 4 Context you can use Server level context and store your `AUTH_TOKEN` there, but you will still need some place where you get a new token and refresh it when it expires. Again, you can implement this logic in the custom `authModule`. I.e. you can still keep that custom module and store the `AUTH_TOKEN` in Loopback Context at the same time. This will be absolutely OK, but it will make the code a bit more complex from my point of view.